# preg_match validating two words in a string

Tags: php, string, validation, preg-match

**Problem:**

Trying to validate that a form field has at least two words before submission.

**PHP-code:**

```
if (!preg_match('^\w+\s\w+$', $_POST['freetext']))
{
    $error_array[] = 'missingwords';
}
```

**Current status:**

An error is being printed even when I have typed in two words with space in between. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
   if (str_word_count($str)<3){
   // message

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!preg_match('#^\w+\s\w+#', $_POST['freetext']))
{
    $error_array[] = 'missingwords';
}
```

Two problems:

1. You need delimiters for the pattern. I added #
2. I deleted the $ mark, because you want at least 2 words. If the $ mark is there, only string with exactly 2 words will get pass!

Answer (score 0):

PCRE regexen need to be [delimited](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

```
'/^\w+\s\w+$/'
```

You need to turn on error reporting, it would have told you about it.